# How can we cite a figure in latex which is taken from any website?

Tags: floats, citing

I'm writing my thesis for which I had to take some pictures of hardware components used in my project. Please guide me how to cite those websites and refer to those pictures?

Comment: It seems that your question concerns bibliography and "style" rather than LaTeX. A thesis often must follow a particular set of rules regarding references etc. Does your department use a  "style sheet" or something similar? How do you organise other references, e.g. to literature that you use?

Comment: You should cite the sources of the images just like you would cite the sources of other prior intellectual contributions. The precise format of the citations will depend importantly on the stylistic requirements that apply to your thesis.

Comment: Since you will be citing material from web pages, somehow volatile, it is helpful to add "Last Access" and the date, in the reference. (And if possible keep the link updated. Some reviewers checks the links!!)